# What does ¡palabra! mean as an interjection?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

In [Huevos Verdes Con Jamón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huevos_verdes_con_jam%C3%B3n), there is a line that reads

> Juan Ramón - "¿Podrías comerlos con una cabra?"
>   Unnamed Protagonist - "No podría, **¡Palabra!**  comerlos con una cabra."

I understand that "palabra" typically means "word", but that doesn't make sense here.  I assume that the speaker is expressing frustration (similar to how he says "¡basta ya!" elsewhere in the book), but I'm not sure if there's more meaning or nuance than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Given that **Green Eggs and Ham** is a children's book originally written and published in English, in the United States, I'd say yeah, the meaning from your linked question is the same..*

My point is that your question stems from a Spanish translation of American English poetry.
Dr. Seuss' poetry is well known for it's brevity in incessant repeating rhythms, and I'd say that using `¡Palabra!` instead of `Te lo prometo` as a translation for.

> I could not, **would not**, eat them with a goat!
>
> No podría **¡Palabra!** comerlos con una cabra

Degraded down to

> I could not, **I tell you**, eat them with a goat!

...is the best translation to use because `palabra` rhymes best with `cabra` in some unaccountable syllabic way.

To translate it literally would shatter the rhythm that the translator has created.

> No podría !No lo haría! comerlos con una cabra

*I guess it would work if you used an animal that ends in `ía`*

---

To beat a dead horse, like Dr. Seuss.

### Palabra = "I tell you, I say!" *think [Foghorn Leghorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foghorn_Leghorn#In_other_media)* :)

This usage shows up in [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RUl938s), if you're looking for solid research and not my ramblings.

> **Palabra.** Interjección usada para garantizar la verdad de lo que se afirma.
> (=interjection used to guarantee the truth of what is being asserted)

Answer (score 0):

Palabra means "word". In this case, it means he is giving you his "word of honor".